# Match/VLOOKUP with Embedded IF statement to return one of two columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've looked high and low for this formula but nothing seems to come close. I would really appreciate the help. In Worksheet 1 I have a list of names. In Worksheet 2, I have column A with names, column B with yes/no, column C with valueA, and column D with valueB. What I want to do is look up the name in worksheet 2 (could be MATCH or VLOOKUP, I think), and once the name is found, check if column B is yes or no. If yes, return column C's valueA. If no (or FALSE), return column D's valueB. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

The two most common ways of doing lookups in Excel are VLOOKUP (or HLOOKUP), or a combination of INDEX and MATCH. The latter method is slightly more complex, but more flexible.

Applying it to your problem, you need to perform a lookup three times, within an IF formula: if looking up Column B yields YES, look up Column C, else look up Column D. So it might look like this:

```
=IF(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet1!A:A,0))="yes",INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet1!A:A,0)),INDEX(Sheet2!D:D,MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet1!A:A,0)))
```

In future, give it a shot on your own - to whatever extent you're able - and then paste your working here so we can help you improve it!

Comment: Thank you, Josh! You saved the day. That was exactly what I needed. It's perfect, minus the fact that it is using the ugly #N/A. Do you know how I can get rid of that? The previous formula I was using was =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A2,'HK-zh'!A:D,4,FALSE)),"--EXCLUDED--",VLOOKUP($A2,'HK-zh'!A:D,4,false)). With your wonderful new formula, can I embed it inside another IF like here somehow - to turn the #N/A into an --EXCLUDED--?

Comment: You're welcome :) Just wrap an IFNA (that is, if formula yields #N/A, give an alternative result) on the outside, so: `=IFNA(IF(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet1!A:A,0))="yes",INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet1!A:A,0)),INDEX(Sheet2!D:D,MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet1!A:A,0))),"--EXCLUDED--")`